# Retrieve each item in category

Tags: mysql, laravel, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am creating an application using flutter and Laravel as the backend (for API) and MySQL as the DB.

I have a list of categories and each category contains a number of items. I have been able to retrieve the category names and the length of the entire category with these lines of code

```
categoryController.categoryList[index].name.toString(),
categoryController.categoryList.length,
```

I want to retrieve each item individually from a category and display them on the screen, but I am having issues with how to implement this.

Excerpts of my code are below...

This is the Category model

```
class Category {
  int? id = 0;
  String? name = "";

  Category({this.id, this.name});

  Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }
}
```

This is the CategoryController class using getx

```
class CategoryController extends GetxController {
  final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

  CategoryController({required this.categoryRepository});

  List<Category> _categoryList = [];

  List<Category> get categoryList => _categoryList;

  Future<void> getCategoryList() async {
    Response response = await categoryRepository.getCategoryList();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      _categoryList = [];

      for (var item in response.body) {
        _categoryList.add(Category.fromJson(item));
      }

      update();
    } else {
      // Print error msg here...
    }
  }
}
```

This is the Category Repository file

```
class CategoryRepository {
  final ApiClient apiClient;

  CategoryRepository({required this.apiClient});

  Future<Response> getCategoryList() async {
    return await apiClient.getData(ProjectConstants.CATEGORY_URI);
  }
}
```

This is laravel controller for category (the index file).

```
public function index()
    {
        return CategoryResource::collection(Category::select('id', 'name')->get());
    }
```

This is an image of my category db in MySQL

[image]

Each of these categories in the image has a number of products, and that is what I want to retrieve per each category.

If I can retrieve the content of each category, I can display them in flutter, so there is no need to show the UI code for each category screen.

The main issue here is how to retrieve the individual content in each category. For instance, if category A has 4 items, I should be able to retrieve all those 4 items. I do not mean the length but rather the actual content of each category

Comment: So the items in a category you want are products, right? Aren't they also sent in your data structure in the json? Then you can extend your category with a list of products, parse them like id and name (be careful, in this case a list!) and then access them

Comment: Thanks for the response but if you don't mind, can you explain further or even be more detailed by attempting to write code as an answer to it?

Comment: Is `category` table and those items under it stored in the same table? How do you translate your current retrieval code into plain MySQL query?

Comment: @KennedyOwusu As per the category model, i see only you are returning category from the BE. Ask your BE developer to update the response of the API. It should return category and its contents. Can you please share the response of the current API?